# Cypress represent the OR in a loop

Tags: angular, testing, cypress, e2e-testing, e2e

I am trying to test the input values of a table, but I cannot represent the OR, nor can I skip a cell of a table.
the table is cycled, it has all positive values, except in a cell where in automatic it is negative so either I have to skip that cell, or I have to check all the cells if it is negative or positive...

```
  cy.get('my-table > .my-table tbody > tr > td:not(:nth-child(5)) > input:not([disabled])')
  .each(el => {
    cy.wrap(el).should('have.value', '0.1234' || 'have.value', '-0.1234');
  });
```

Already entering the `td: not(:nth-child(5))` should skip a cell (the one with the negative value) while it doesn't... so I tried with a `||` condition to test if it's positive or negative but it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are checking the value to be one of either 0.1234 or -0.1234, you can use this:

```js
cy.get('my-table > .my-table tbody > tr > td:not(:nth-child(5)) > input:not([disabled])').each(($ele) => {
  expect($ele.val().trim()).to.be.oneOf(['0.1234', '-0.1234'])
})
```

Comment: and how do i fit it into my cycle? gives me errors

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by cycle. And what errors are you getting ? I have updated my answer.

Comment: no nothing, sorry I wrote it before you changed your code. now it works, thanks!